# In what order are the variables multiplied

Tags: c++

In what order will the variables be multiplied.

```
int a = 5;
int b = 3;

a *= b;
```

is that

```
a = a X b;
```

or

```
a = b X a;
```

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: @Pierre difference would happen in case of non communitative multiplication like that of matrices

Comment: @suman given that whoever implements matrices also needs to implement matrix multiplication, this is not a language issue, but an implementation issue.

Comment: @Zeta yes but order will be decided by the programmer .

Comment: matrix A * matrix B , will be different from Matrix B * matrix A.

Comment: @suman Do you want to create your own Matrix class or do you want to use an existing one?

Comment: @Pierre i am using GLM matrix class.

Comment: wanted to know with this syntax how matrix multiplication would be ordered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard defines that `a *= b` is the same as `a = a * b`, unless the types have been overloaded.

See section `[expr.ass]` in the standard (section *5.17 Assignment and compound assignment operators* in the C++11 version).

For `a * b * c`, the operation is grouped left-to-right, i.e. `(a * b) * c`. See `[expr.mul]`. This also holds for overloaded operators, however, as overloaded operators can do all wacky kinds of things, their resulting effect can be arbitrary.

Comment: @suman keep in mind that any matrix operation or matrix-like class is **not** defined in the standard (at least up to C++17, not sure about C++20). Therefore, whatever matrix implementation you use might define `*=` or `*` in some weird way.

Comment: If you look at the source code of GLM, you can see the operator*= is implemented according to the specification of the standard. https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/838d3fed97bd2ca6bdcec102bf918153f54f2316/glm/detail/type_mat2x2.inl